# Insert 24 hour period into database

Tags: sql

This is more of a best practices question although I am struggling with the sql but the 2 are linked. I want to insert into a sql database the date and time for the forthcoming 24 hour period starting at 6am.

I think it would be best to run a schedualed SQL job at say 1am for the forthcoming day.  This would create one column and 24 rows spanning for example 20/03/2013 06:00 to 21/03/2013 05:00.

thanks

Comment: This is very dependent on what RDBMS you are using, as they all handle date/time differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the date time functions.  Here is an example of how it could be done (in SQL Server):

```
insert into t(thedatetime)
    select dateadd(hour, hrs.hr, cast(CAST(getdate() as DATE) as datetime))
    from (select 0 as hr union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
          select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all
          select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all
          select 12 union all select 13 union all select 14 union all select 15 union all
          select 16 union all select 17 union all select 18 union all select 19 union all
          select 20 union all select 21 union all select 22 union all select 23
         ) as hrs;
```

In Oracle, the `select` would might be:

```
   select trunc(sysdate) + hrs.hr/24.0
```

And there are similar constructs for other databases.

This is assuming that it is running after midnight on the date in question.  For the next day, you would have to add one day to the current date.

Comment: thanks, I used your query above and I have amended it somewhat and created an sql job for it to run each day at the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for `ORACLE`

```
SELECT To_date('22-03-2013 '||(CASE WHEN (6+(LEVEL-1))>12 THEN (CASE WHEN LEVEL>19 THEN (LEVEL-12-7) ELSE (6+(LEVEL-1))-12 END) ELSE (6+(LEVEL-1)) END)||':00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') 
FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL<=24;
```

Comment: @Art Thanks !! i have edited the query now it will return 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

This works in Postgres:

```
select timestamp '2013-03-30 06:00' + interval '1' hour * i
from generate_series(0,23) i;
```